# How to handle shell prompt in maven

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have a pom.xml file that executes a shell script, and the shell script has the prompt

"Enter 'YES' to have this script continue:"

How do I tell maven 1)Parse the prompt, 2)Enter YES when it sees the prompt?

Or at the least, an answer to the second question above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bash-maven-plugin and had this in my pom.xml file

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.atlassian.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>bash-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>execute-shell</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <script>./build_dm.sh --accept-warning</script>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. One of my plugins was designed to display some information to user and proceed only after confirmation. When I had to use it on our CI build server, I ended up with this:

> echo 'y' | mvn release:branch ...

I assume that you could either go with this approach (if it works for you), or use `gmaven` plugin to execute Groovy code before the execution of your shell script that would write needed string to system input.

Comment: Is this inside an exec plugin? Can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

You're using an interactive script in non-interactive mode. The script should have a parameter (ie. --non-interactive, or -y / -n, etc.) which disable the prompt and force the answer.

Comment: No it does NOT have a non-interactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

Setup script run as `yes | ./script` in pom.xml

Comment: That does NOT work. I get [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (sqlncli-build-configure) on project sqlncli-build: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "YES | /opt/jenkins/workspace/flexip/sqlncli/sqlncli-build/target/dependency/sqlncli-11.0.1790.0/build_dm.sh" (in directory "/opt/jenkins/workspace/flexip/sqlncli/sqlncli-build/target/dependency/sqlncli-11.0.1790.0"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/README.distribution), writing a wrapper script which, in turn, calls the interactive script.

To install it on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install expect
```

This script should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn ./test.sh
expect "Enter 'YES' to have this script continue:"
send "YES\r"
interact
```

Comment: Posting example usage instead of referencing external manual is expect-ed on SO ;)

Comment: So, nobody reads manuals anymore, that's it? :P Fine, I'll do it.