# Maven exec plugin: read user input

Tags: bash, maven, plugins

I am trying to get the maven exec plugin to execute a deployment script that requires user input.

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <executions>
  <execution>
    <id>ExitCompilation</id>
    <phase>compile</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
      <executable>${env.PROJECT_HOME}/deployment.sh</executable>
      <arguments>
         <argument>deploy</argument>
         <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}/deployment.tar.gz</argument>
      </arguments>
      <workingDirectory>${env.PROJECT_HOME}</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
....
```

The script (which is a bash script)

```
${env.PROJECT_HOME}/deployment.sh
```

runs fine, but requires user input in form of a 'y' or 'n' to confirm or deny actually deploying.

How would i go about sending the 'y' to the script via the exec plugin?

Changing the script itself should be seen as a last resort as it would be problematic for the project.

Comment: There is a similar question here, along with a number of possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716582/how-to-handle-shell-prompt-in-maven. In that question the original poster ended up using the [bash-maven-plugin](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/bash-maven-plugin). Could be worth a try.

Comment: I did see the bash plugin, but it seems to require an argument to disable the interactivity. The script in question has no such switch.